# Error in instr function in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

### Getting error in Teradata SQL

```
select Instr(column_name, '|',   -1) + 1  from db.table_name;
```

### Getting error as

```
SELECT Failed.  [6706] The string contains an untranslatable character.
```

Not able to find which special character or record is making trouble here.

Answer (score 1):

Use Translate_chk function to check which characters are not translatable. I think it is mostly comes when a function under the hood tried to convert from latin to unicode. Check the below link how to use the function and result codes.

https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference%2FB035-1145-160K%2Fusa1472241160802.html%23wwID0EKCDQ.

Use Instr(TRANSLATE(column_name USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE), '|',   -1)) + 1  in your code instead of column_name should work. Problem with this it result in null values when you have untranslatable characters